# What folder should I find the wxWidgets in?

Tags: directory, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I have made a full installation of 'Code::Blocks 20.03', using the suggested default directory. So I have the following folder containing Code::Blocks

'C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks'

Assuming that 'wxWidgets' was part of this installation, what folder will the wxWidgets have been unpacked to?

I need this location for input to the, create a 'wxWidget Projects' wizard.

Comment: no you don't. The wizard will find that automatically.

Comment: wxWidgets is not included in codeblocks.  You need to install it separately.  You can get source packages and several precompiled binaries from [here](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/tag/v3.1.4).  Be sure to follow the directions carefully.

Comment: It doesn't though.NB I am using Windows 10.

Comment: It looks to me as if 'wxWidgets' might be there, The wizard gives me a choice of using various versions of it and also has the string "$(#wx)" as the chosen wxWidgets location. When I click 'Next' though, in the wizard, it says 'Please select a valid location'.

Comment: @uset151522, as New Pagodi said - please grab wxWidgets sources and build it.